# Get the ranking result of a specific Elasticsearch result

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am running ES and PHP. I am trying to display stats when I view a specific document.

Suppose you have any search result in Elasticsearch, like this list of big cities sorted by population desc:

sort order ranking - name - population

rank 1 - CITY A - pop. 5m

rank 2 - CITY B - pop. 4m

rank 3 - CITY C - pop. 3m

When I now view CITY B via its ID on my website, I would like to show its sort order ranking (#2 -- the current city is on rank #2 in the earlier search) and a link to the previous (#1) and next document  (#3) of my earlier search.

How can this be done? I could not find anything about this topic.